# How do use a variable in a php echo to pass an id to a div?

Tags: php, css

I am creating a random musical note generator using PHP and HTML. I have placed all the positions for the musical notes in a css file and would like to do something like this:

```
echo 'div id=note_array[rand_numbs[1]]  class="note_1st"> &#x2669; </div>';
```

The note array provides something like id="E", or id="A". Of course, it doesn't work. Is there anyway to pass a variable in echo as an id for a tag?

Comment: Your div should start with an opening bracket, <, unless there's some reason otherwise.

Comment: And yes, anything you output in php becomes part of your HTML whether it's text, part of a tag, a tag name, whatever - it just has to end up as valid syntax when it gets to the browser.

Comment: What exactly is the structure of $note_array?

Answer (score 2):

You have error in the concatenation and your open div, also I guess `note_array[rand_numbs[1]]` is an array and should be `$note_array['rand_numbs'][1]`

```
echo '<div id="'.$note_array['rand_numbs'][1].'" class="note_1st"> &#x2669; </div>';
```

I prefer write it in this way

```
echo "<div id='{$note_array['rand_numbs'][1]}' class='note_1st'> &#x2669; </div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `echo 'div id='.note_array[rand_numbs[1]].' class="note_1st"> ♩ ';`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to echo it like so:

```
echo 'div="' . note_array[rand_numbs[1]] . '" class="note_1st"';
```

Using dot notation you can "glue" together a string that contains a variable or a piece of an array like you're doing here.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
echo 'div id=note_array[rand_numbs[1]]  class="note_1st"> &#x2669; </div>';
```

use this:

```
echo 'div id="' . note_array[rand_numbs[1]] . '"  class="note_1st"> &#x2669; </div>';
```

You need to enclose the value of id into quotes, also you can use dot notation to solve your problem.

Also, you can use dot notation at any string in php.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I had multiple problems. I left out < in the opening div and forgot to add in the "s for the id. 

Thanks again for the help.

Comment: You are welcome. If your problem is solved, then please accept the answer which helped you the most.

Answer (score 0):

With [echo](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php), you can use the dot (.) and the comma (,). This last is sometimes more pratical than the dot. It's more easier to write the code with it. Also, you didn't always need concatenation and you can get better performance (a few).

Of course, your code will not work also if you forget the `$`. I guess too such like Emilio Gort that the `note_array` is in fact a var (an array). So, to solve your issue, I think you can do something like this :

```
echo '<div id="',$note_array['rand_numbs'],'" class="note_1st"> &#x2669; </div>';
```

You didn't mention the content of your array. It isn't clear for me. So, you will maybe need to add some changes such like this :

```
echo '<div id="',$note_array['rand_numbs']['1'],'" class="note_1st"> &#x2669; </div>';
echo '<div id="',$note_array['rand_numbs']['SomethingeElse'],'" class="note_1st"> &#x2669; </div>';
```

You can use `['1']` or `[1]`. The both syntax will work. The first is supposed to allow some better performance.